# Strange behavior on Gnome after update on from 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: 13.04, gnome, gnome-classic

I made an automatic update on my Ubuntu 13.10 (from 13.04) system today. Since this point of time, I am in really big trouble. I use a VNC server with Gnome classic, after the update my Gnome was gone. So i tried everything. Checked the `xstartup` file of `vncserver`.

Right now I reached a point where I can't find the answer. The logfile says that `gnome-session-fallback` is missing, even directly after I installed it with apt-get (tried it serveral times, installing, uninstalling and so on).

I have no chance to use it as you can see in this terminal copy:

```
root@ip-xxx:~/.vnc# apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gnome-session-fallback
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,914 B of archives.
After this operation, 247 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package gnome-session-fallback.
(Reading database ... 210977 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking gnome-session-fallback (from .../gnome-session-fallback_1%3a3.6.2-0ubuntu15_all.deb) ...
Setting up gnome-session-fallback (1:3.6.2-0ubuntu15) ...

root@ip-xxx:~/.vnc# gnome-session-fallback
The program 'gnome-session-fallback' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

If you have some idea, please give me a hint...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

gnome-session-fallback is a transitional package, which causes gnome-system-flashback to be installed.  It actually *is* installed, but the bash suggestion tool doesn't know about the change, so it keeps suggesting that you install it.

As to your actual problem, there are several related questions posted here on AU, but none of them have a real solution (as of 10/22/2013):

- [Ubuntu 13.10 VNC server not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361625/ubuntu-13-10-vnc-server-not-working)
- [Does gnome-fallback.desktop require accelerated graphics in 13.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361617/does-gnome-fallback-desktop-require-accelerated-graphics-in-13-10)

Answer (score 0):

I needed the graphical interface, so I removed everything from Gnome and installed KDE. I added the line

```
startkde &
```

in my `.vnc/xtstartup` file. Now the graphical interface with VNC works again. KDE starts with a crash, but it seems to run. I will try to find out where the crash happens.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the script /usr/bin/gnome-session-fallback is missing from the package.

On 13.04 the script has the following two lines:

```
#! /bin/sh
exec gnome-session --session gnome-fallback "$@"
```

You may try to create this script yourself and see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you might install xfce4 desktop and enjoy a neat and full-featured evnironment through VNC, provided you add a line `startxfce4 &` in  `.vnc/xstartup` file. The line `exec x11/xinit/xinitrc` should be hashed instead.

I experienced similar inconvenience and since gnome-session simply does not work I decided so switch to xfce4. No bugs, no hassle. Just fine.