# Ubuntu 13.10 VNC server not working

Tags: 13.10

I have installed ubuntu 13.10 and set up turbovnc, tigervnc, vnc4server and none of those vnc servers works.
Previously i had ubuntu 13.04 and all worked well.

I am using gnome-session-fallback for the vnc session but it seams that the desktop session does not load, the vnc window is filled with a gray background image and the cursor is an "x".

Anyone managed to get a vnc session working on ubuntu 13.10.
(i do not want x11vnc, or vino. Those work but it is not what i want.)

Thank you.

Comment: There is more discussion about this at http://askubuntu.com/questions/361617/does-gnome-fallback-desktop-require-accelerated-graphics-in-13-10.

Answer (score 1):

gnome-fallback package in Ubuntu 13.10 seems to be broken. to fix your issue, you should install xfce desktop and configure the .vnc/.xstartup file in order to start the xfce4 desktop environment.  (you add the line startxfce4 &)  and you should be good to go

Hope this help